# Wildfly throws error when launching Standalone

Tags: java, wildfly

I am trying to build in MS active directory authentication for my standalone application in Wildfly 9.

In standalone-full.xml under `<security-domains>` I've added:

```
<security-domain name="ldap-login-module" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="userProvider" value="ldap://192.168.13.7/CN=user,DC=my,DC=example,DC=com"/> 
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

In web.xml I've added:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>ldap-login-module</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

And I created my jboss-web.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>ldap-login-module</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

When I deploy the application and try to open it in the browser, I get this error in server.log:

```
2015-07-14 13:02:33,109 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sienna.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.ldap-login-module]"]}
```

Before adding the above xml, the application would deploy and run normally.  What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the code I added in standalone-full.xml to standalone.xml, and that solved the issue.